# My ListView wouldn't work. I'm missing out something here

Tags: java, android, listview

I casted this line: lv1.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this); because it creates a red squiggly line. 
Am I using the onItemClick function properly?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lv1;
private String lv_arr[] = {
        "Android",
        "iPhone",
        "Blackberry",
        "AndroidPeople"
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);
    //by using setAdapter method in ListView, we can add string array in list

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View v, int position, long arg3){

    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked" + lv_arr[position],       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` doesn't implement `OnItemClickListener`, which is why it was giving you the "red squigly line".

You should change the class declaration to:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
```

this will mean that you don't have to cast your `MainActivity` to an `OnItemClickListener` when setting it to your `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement OnItemClickListener or just if you can write instead

```
 lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked" + lv_arr[position],       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have each row with its customized `onClickListener()`, you'll need to extend an `ArrayAdapter` (for instance) and implement the `onClickListener()` for each row within the `getView()` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
  // Speaking very vaguely, convertView represents each of your rows
  if (convertView == null) {
    ...
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(final View v) {
        // Whetever you need
        ...
      }
    }
  });
  else
    ...

  // Rest of your implementation
  ...

  return convertView; 
}
```